# Trouble passing a parameter to a class in C#

Tags: c#, parameters

I'm having a bit of trouble passing this parameter to a class i have.  Does anybody have any ideas?

Class 1's code:

```
public void DriveRecursion(string retPath)
{
    //recurse through files.  Let user press 'ok' to move onto next step        
    // string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(retPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    string pattern = " *[\\~#%&*{}/<>?|\"-]+ *";
    //string replacement = "";
    Regex regEx = new Regex(pattern);

    string[] fileDrive = Directory.GetFiles(retPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    List<string> filePath = new List<string>();



    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
    try
    {
        foreach (string fileNames in fileDrive)
        {

            if (regEx.IsMatch(fileNames))
            {
                string fileNameOnly = Path.GetFileName(fileNames);
                string pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileNames);

                DataGridViewRow dgr = new DataGridViewRow();
                filePath.Add(fileNames);
                dgr.CreateCells(dataGridView1);
                dgr.Cells[0].Value = pathOnly;
                dgr.Cells[1].Value = fileNameOnly;
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dgr);

                 \\I want to pass fileNames to my FileCleanup Method
                 \\I tried this:
               \\SanitizeFileNames sf = new SanitizeFileNames();
               \\sf.Add(fileNames); <-- this always gets an error..plus it is not an action i could find in intellisense


            }

            else
            {
                continue;
            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(retPath + "ErrorLog.txt");
        sw.Write(e);

    }
}
```

Class 2's code:

```
public class SanitizeFileNames
{

    public void FileCleanup(string fileNames)
    {
        string regPattern = " *[\\~#%&*{}/<>?|\"-]+ *";
        string replacement = "";
        Regex regExPattern = new Regex(regPattern);
    }
```

What i want to do in SanitizeFileNames is do a foreach through the FileNames & FilePath and replace invalid chars (as defined in my Regex pattern).  So, something along the lines of this:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"S:\File_Renames.txt"))
{
    //Sanitize and remove invalid chars  
    foreach (string Files2 in filePath)
    {
        try
        {
            string filenameOnly = Path.GetFileName(Files2);
            string pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(Files2);
            string sanitizedFilename = regEx.Replace(filenameOnly, replacement);
            string sanitized = Path.Combine(pathOnly, sanitizedFilename);
            sw.Write(sanitized + "\r\n");
            System.IO.File.Move(Files2, sanitized);
        }
        //error logging
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            StreamWriter sw2 = new StreamWriter(@"S:\Error_Log.txt");
            sw2.Write("ERROR LOG");
            sw2.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ex + "\r\n");
            sw2.Flush();
            sw2.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm having trouble passing the fileNames into my SanitizeFileNames class.  Can anybody help me?

Comment: "Having trouble". What kind of trouble? Can't compile? Runtime exceptions? Other errors?

Comment: I edited to show what I tried.  sf.Add isn't an option -- it's not in intellisense plus I get errors.  I need to find a way to pass this param onto my FileCleanup method.

Comment: @yeah: you're confusing yourself. "`fileNames` holds a single filename. Rename it to "`fileName`". Then you'll see that you're trying to pass multiple filenames into your `SanitizeFileNames.FileCleanup` class, and it only takes one!

Comment: @yeah: in fact, you're confusing yourself further by using bad terminology: you don't pass parameters to a **class**. You pass parameters to a _method_ of a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        try
        {
            foreach (string fileNames in fileDrive)
            {

                if (regEx.IsMatch(fileNames))
                {
                    string fileNameOnly = Path.GetFileName(fileNames);
                    string pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileNames);

                    DataGridViewRow dgr = new DataGridViewRow();
                    filePath.Add(fileNames);
                    dgr.CreateCells(dataGridView1);
                    dgr.Cells[0].Value = pathOnly;
                    dgr.Cells[1].Value = fileNameOnly;
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dgr);

                    new SanitizeFileNames().FileCleanup(fileNames);
                }

                else
                {
                    continue;
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: new SanitizeFileNames.FileCleanup(fileNames);
 gives me the error:  FileCleanup(string) is a 'method' but used like a 'type'.  Do i need to somehow edit my method or class for SanitizeFileNames?

Comment: It should be new SanitizeFileNames().FileCleanup(fileNames). (Note the brackets after SanitizeFileNames.)

Comment: ah yes, my mistake.  did not notice the brackets.  Thank you much!

Answer (score 1):

The parameter type should be an enumerable collection of some sort: a list or an array would do. Also, strings are immutable so you could return a list of cleaned up filenames:

```
public class SanitizeFilenames
{
    public List<string> FileCleanUp(IEnumerable<string> filenames)
    {
        var cleanedFileNames = new List<string>();

        var invalidChars = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();
        foreach(string file in filenames)
        {
            if(file.IndexOfAny(invalidChars) != -1)
            {
                // clean the file name and add it to the cleanedFileNames list
            }
            else 
            {
                // nothing to clean here
                cleanedFileNames.Add(file);
            }
        }

        return cleanedFileNames;
    }
}
```

Comment: As you say it should be a collection "of some sort" som please make it just that, actually, it should be a sequence "of some sort" so let's make it an IEnumerable<string> rather than a List<string>.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to pass a dirty name to the FileCleanup function and get a clean out. Here is how you can do that :

```
public String FileCleanup(string fileNames)
{
    string regPattern = " *[\\~#%&*{}/<>?|\"-]+ *";
    string replacement = "";
    Regex regExPattern = new Regex(regPattern);

    ...

    return cleanName;
}
```

and use it in your code like this:

```
String cleanName = new SanitizeFileNames().FileCleanup(fileNames);
```

where you put the comment.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can create a third class static class and add static variable called files “`public static List<string> Files= new List<string>()`”  as example.
2. When you create the files add the same files to the static variable.
3. When you clean the files loop throw the static variable, and at the end clear it.